# Meter calling python api

Tags: python-2.7, meteor, flask

This is the meteor function and we are not able to call REST API from Meteor

```
'toScaleInstance': function(){
     var Response = HTTP.call("PUT", "0.0.0.0:8765/service/api/v1",
              {
              headers:{"content-type":"application/json"},
              data:{
                    "num":"1", 
                    "project":"projectname"
                   }
              }); 
     console.log(Response);
}
```

it throws "No JSON object could be decoded" and the api is written in python. The same api works fine using curl.

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data "{\"num\":\"1\", \"project\":\"projectname\"}" 0.0.0.0:8765/service/api/v1/
```

Let me know if you need more information. Thank you

python code

```
@app.route("/api/v1/", methods=['PUT'])
def scale():
    """
    docker-compose scale
    """
    req = loads(request.data)
    name = req['project']
    num = req['num']
    """
    some logic
    """
    return jsonify(command='scale')
```

Note: we printed request.data in python and its printing null while called from Meteor and its printing the correct data while requested via curl

Comment: can you post the python code?

Comment: @app.route("/api/v1/", methods=['PUT'])
def scale():
    req = loads(request.data)
    name = req['project']
    num = req['num']
    """
    some code
    """

Comment: doesn't look like the python code returns any json. Please use `jsonify`, if you are using flask

Comment: I have updated the code and we do have a return statement, sorry I did not give complete code had to remove some logic, just to make it small.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your python code is returning any json. Try the following:

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/api/v1', methods=['PUT'])
def scale():
  " docker-compose scale "
  # your logic here
  return jsonify(return_value)
```